# Load <link rel="stylesheet"> raw content into an <style> tag

Tags: javascript, css, dom, iframe, widget

my platform delivers some similar widgets on the same webpage. These widgets are embedded on iframes, and share the same CSS definition among them.

Current version loads this definition using `<link rel="stylesheet">` tag. But, I am thinking to change loading strategy to css inline definition inside `<style>` tag.

1. Load base javascript on target page
2. Create a hidden iframe, and load CSS `<link>` on it (async document.write call)
3. Set this CSS content into javascript var on target page context.

Steps 1 and 2 are already implemented and working. Now, how should step 3 be implemented?

After some new tests, I'll post here any positive results.

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* want to use Javascript for something that can be done (or at least done easily) with pure CSS. There are a lot of people who don't have JS enabled...I don't think you want to limit their access to your site. What you are looking for can be done with the CSS `@import` rule. It's pretty simple -- all you need to do is place `@import "path/to/css/file"` above *all* your other style rules. The path is relative to the current stylesheet; if it's in an HTML file then it's relative to the HTML file.

For example, if you had a domain like stackunderflow.com, a stylesheet in the top-level folder, and a stylesheet called `style2.css` in a folder called `extra-styles`, then you could import the stylesheet from `extra-styles` via a relative path: `@import "extra-styles/style2.css"` Another good thing about this is that it's supported in almost all browsers.

Comment: I want to avoid calls to to my server. I will load CSS content once inside iframe. After, I put it in an variable. When one widget request css content, I will inject it dynamically inside a <style> tag, into widget (iframe) document. My main issue is remove server side calls and use an already available locally content.